# Redis with express and passport

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to using Redis  with my exsiting  application

Here is my app.js code

```
var express = require('express'),
  request = require('request'),
  http = require('http'),
  path = require('path');  
var app = express();
var routes = require('./routes');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash'); 
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
var policies = require('./policies/admin');
var config = require('./config');
 require('./libs/passport')(passport); 

 app.configure(function () { 
   app.use(express.session({ secret: 'secertkey', cookie: { maxAge : 2592000000 } })); // session secret
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
});
```

Which is working fine.

I want to use Rediss along with passport,

Is this possible and how can i do

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pass the express-session store into connect-redis to create a RedisStore constructor.

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore(options),
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```

for reference 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis

Comment: what does this secret do also can i use have you used cookie-sessions ?